# Sort and filter functions on WPF GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an WPF application which contains a listview with a gridview. I'm trying to implement sorting and filtering functions to that gridview.

I find that Windows Seven explorer grid is particularly well made for that functions with sort on header click and filter on click on the small arrow at the right of the header :

**Explorer grid**

[image]

I looked for explorer like GridView on the internet but I didn't found what I'm searching for.

So can you give me some suggestions on the best way to implement that functions or some links which can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `DataGrid` there you can define your custom headers. And also you can provide an `ICollectionView` as Itemsssource for the `DataGrid` and on that `ICollectionView` you can define a Filter.

Take a look at it. If you need any further help, just let us know

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you!